# Delphi - Why Use VarArrayPut?

Tags: arrays, delphi, variant

I am using Delphi Rio to control Excel.  I am reading and writing whole columns, so I am using VarArrayCreate to create an array of variant to read a column's worth of data.  I update specific portions of the data, and then write the update back to the Variant array. When done, I write the whole Variant array back to my column.

While looping through the array, I read a single element of the array.... and potentially write back to that element of the array...

```
... read from the array
CellText := arrData[i, 1];

... possibly update data

... write the updated data back to the array
arrData[i,1] := CellPadded;
```

This works without issue.  My question has to do with writing the update back to the array.  I ran into the function VarArrayPut.  Why would I use this as opposed to directly putting the data back into the array like in the code above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is that `VarArrayPut` is the same as array accessor (square brackets syntax) and in the end they both invoke internal procedure `_VarArrayPut` in unit `System.Variants`. Likewise reading value from the array using square brackets or `VarArrayGet` will result in a call to internal function `_VarArrayGet`. You can easily check that yourself by stepping into (<kbd>F7</kbd>) the assignment `arrData[i, 1] := CellPadded;` during a debugging session.

That said, the variant array accessor is just a syntactic sugar that Delphi compiler provides to make the code shorter and more readable, but that is a subject of personal taste. Consider the following:

```
arrData[i, 1] := CellPadded;
{ vs }
VarArrayPut(arrData, CellPadded, [i, 1]);
```

In case you do a lot of data manipulation and you're not resizing the array during the processing you might as well do it in a [`VarArrayLock`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarArrayLock) .. [`VarArrayUnlock`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarArrayUnlock) block to gain some extra performance by direct access to array data bypassing all the sanity checks and API calls that `_VarArrayGet` and `_VarArrayPut` do internally:

```
{ untested, use at your own risk }
{$POINTERMATH ON}
var
  Data: PVariant; { in case of variant array of varVariant }
  LBound1, LBound2, HBound2: Integer;

Data := VarArrayLock(arrData);
try
  LBound1 := VarArrayLowBound(V, 1);
  LBound2 := VarArrayLowBound(V, 2);
  HBound2 := VarArrayHighBound(V, 2);
  { access element value at [i, j] }
  (Data + i - LBound1 + (j - LBound2) * (HBound2 - LBound2 + 1))^ := CellPadded;

  { ... }

finally
  VarArrayUnlock(arrData);
end;
```

This won't of course work with jagged arrays.